# Does it follow java conventions to only provide a getter for collections?

Tags: java

I recently encountered code like the following:

```
public List<Item> getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    }
    return this.items;
}
```

and crucially, no setter method.

So if you wanted to add to the arrayList, you would have to do

```
foo.getItems().add(...)
```

rather than

```
foo.setItems(myArrayList)
```

I've not seen this idiom before, and I can't say I like it, but when I generated some mapping code using mapstruct.org (great tool by the way), mapstruct handles it fine and correctly generates code that uses the getter as a setter as well.

I'm just wondering - is this a common idiom that I've somehow missed? It seems pointless to me, but perhaps there is some wisdom behind it I'm not seeing?

Comment: I think this is confusing. When I have only getter, I expect unmodifiable collection to return. I'd better name it `getItemList()` to show that elements can be put on it.

Comment: It's actually better, IMO, than accepting any unknown list from the outside. At least, the class can guarantee that its List is mutable, and is an ArrayList. An even better idea would be to avoid exposing the list, and to provide an addItem() method.

Comment: `setItems()` is also confusing. "set" means "set if empty or replace existing". `addItems()` would be more clear.

Comment: @JBNizet It is better but only in the sense that closing but not locking your front door is safer than leaving it wide open.

Comment: @biziclop agreed, hence the second part of my comment: don't expose the list, mutate it via a dedicated addItem() method.

Answer (score 7):

#### It is common but it is not recommended.

The problem isn't with the lazy initialisation (that part is fine) but the exposure of what should be an implementation detail. Once you expose the actual, mutable(!) list object you store in your field, the caller of the code can do anything with the list, even things you don't expect.

They could for example remove objects when really all you want to allow is `add()`. They could modify it from different threads, making your code break in interesting and frustrating ways. They could even cast it to a raw `List` and fill it with entirely different types of objects, making your code throw `ClassCastException`s.

**In other words, it makes it impossible to enforce class invariants.**

Note that there are two things that work together to cause this problem:

1. The exposure of an object stored in a field.
2. And the fact the object is mutable.

If any of those two aren't true, there's no problem. So this is fine:

```
public String getFoo() {
   return this.foo;
}
```

Because `String` is immutable. And this is fine too:

```
public List<String> getFooList() {
   return new ArrayList<>( this.fooList );
}
```

Because now you're returning a defensive copy and not the actual object. (However, if the elements of the lists were mutable, you'd be in trouble again.)

---

#### There is a more subtle variation to this problem...

Imagine this scenario:

```
public class Foo { 
   private List<String> list;
   public Foo( List<String> list ) {
     this.list = list; // Don't do this
   }
   ...
}
```

This looks perfectly harmless, and you see it in many places. However there is a hidden catch here too: by not making a copy before storing the list, you're in exactly the same situation. You can't stop someone from doing this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add( "nice item" );
Foo foo = new Foo( list );
list.add( "hahahaha" );
list.add( "i've just added more items to your list and you don't know about it." );
list.add( "i'm an evil genius" );
```

**So you should be making defensive copies both before assigning a mutable object to a field and when returning it.**

---

#### If it's so dangerous to expose mutable fields of a class, why don't people make defensive copies all the time then?

Apart from simply not knowing why it isn't a good idea, there are two broad categories of excuses given.

1. **Performance.** Making a copy of an object every time you call a getter is expensive. This is of course true but it's not always as expensive as you'd think. And if you find yourself paying too high a cost for defensive copies, there are usually ways out: for example by designing your classes to be immutable. If all your classes are immutable, you won't need defensive copies, ever.
2. **Only I will call this code and I won't abuse it. Promise.** This is again something that could be valid depending on the situation. If you're writing a small standalone application on your own, it's probably true that you won't abuse it. Or if you're writing a small library but you only expose details of classes that aren't part of the public API. In most other cases though you simply can't be sure that someone somewhere won't abuse it. And when that happens, your code probably won't break with a bang. It usually just starts doing slightly...odd things occasionally. And that's the worst kind of bug to try to find.

Comment: Exactly. This is why you should provide get/set methods and instead of returning the object you should make a copy of it. Either by implementing the cloneable interface or by doing the clone yourself.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things in your code:

1. [Lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization), which is a common approach.
2. Returning a reference to a mutable inner `ArrayList`, which is not fine, because it breaks [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). If you would like to add items to this list, you should expose `addItem()` method only.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not clear how this helps with being lazy. After all, if the goal is to only reluctantly generate objects, with this approach you're generating a new object to signal nothing rather than returning null? You would generate less objects by just having the method be return items; ? And if I have a pre-existing arraylist that I want to populate this structure with, I have to copy all the elements into the new ArrayList that is created, instead of just calling setItems - again, more objects generated?

Comment: @user4782738 returning null would be terrible design. And that would clearly break good coding practice. A caller shouldn't have to test for null every time it uses the returned list. An empty list is the right thing to return to signal "I have 0 item". To "set" the list, all you need is `getItems().clear(); getItems.addAll(myList);`. Note that lazy instantiation of an ArrayList is a useless optimization, IMHO. The list itself already lazily instantiates its backing array. It makes the code more complex for a tiny, probably insignificant performance gain.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common idiom but I wouldn't recommend using it because the caller can do things like this:

```
final List<Item> items = bean.getItems();
final List notItems = (List) items;
notItems.add(new NotAnItem());
```

The caller can also maintain a reference to the `List` and accidentally mutate it later.

I would recommend steering clear of this particular idiom and providing immutable *views* from getters. This will lead to much more stable code in the long run.

So:

```
public List<Item> getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.items);
}
```

And

```
public void setItems(final List<Item> items) {
    if (items == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("items is null");
    }
    this.items = new ArrayList<>(items);
}
```

Comment: Two corrections: `=` instead of `-` in the first snippet and `unmodifiableList` instead of `unmodifyableList` in the second.

Comment: @bcsb1001 thanks, I never could spell.